# Point is no longer accepted when I use the property UpdateSourceTrigger

Tags: wpf, data-binding, double, updatesourcetrigger

I used the property "UpdateSourceTrigger = PropertChanged". I am binding on a double. However, I can not do a '.' anymore, this is simply filtered out / deleted. How can I fix this an continue to use the property?

My Property:

```
private double textBoxZahl;
public double TextBoxZahl 
{ 
    get => textBoxZahl; 
    set
    {
        textBoxZahl = value;
        OnPropertyChanged();
    }
}
```

My TextBox:

```
<TextBox Margin="1,1,1,1" BorderThickness="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Width="auto" x:Name="_NameBox" Background="WhiteSmoke" Text="{Binding ElementName=MaterialList, Path=SelectedItem.TextBoxZahl, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

My binding works fine, but not if I try to use a dot.

Comment: No, in the textbox in the frontend itself, if I want to enter 2.07 and make the point, he just writes nothing like the button would be broken. Is it perhaps because he is the whole time when changing it by the binding write / save but because "2." no valid number and then the whole of the point cuts off?

Comment: The culture of your UI seems to be german. It accepts a `,` as decimal separator. Search the web for "UI culture".